# Generation if a unique id of size less than 11 bytes from a string

Tags: java, security

i am developing a piece of code to generate a unique hexadecimal value from an input string. The output size must be less than 11 bytes which comes as requirement.Can someone please give me an insight into this. I have done the string to binary conversion and then the hexagonal mapping which produces a combination of alphanumeric characters but the size is always greater tha 11 bytes. I also need to regenerate the input from this unique id..Is that possible.....

Thanks in adavance

Comment: if the length/content of your input string is not specified, it is obvious that no possible 1-to-1 mapping to a hex( < 11bytes) exists, as the domain of your string could be much bigger.

Comment: @Winfred: that's what I was trying to say below. I used a few more words though ;-)

Comment: @Joachim Sauer : I just added it as comment :P. Nice that you lay it out properly.

Answer (score 1):

If your result must be absolutely unique **and** your input can be any length, then your task is impossible.

Think of it that way: how many different combinations of 11 bytes are there? 256<sup>11</sup> (or 2<sup>11*8</sup>=2<sup>88</sup>).

That's a big number, right? Yes, but it's not big enough.

For simplicities sake we'll talk about ASCII strings only, so we have 128 different values (in reality there are many more possibilities for a character in a Java `String`, but the principle stays the same. For simplicities sake we also ignore that a `\0` character in a `String` is kind of unlikely).

Now, there are 128<sup>13</sup> different 13-character ASCII strings. That's 2<sup>7*13</sup> or 2<sup>91</sup> different combinations. Obviously you can't have a unique id out of 2<sup>88</sup> possible ids for 2<sup>91</sup> different strings.

Comment: I forgot to mention the input size. it is less than 100 bytes. Does this help

Comment: nowfal: not really. Unless there are additional restrictions (or you can do away with the requirement of unique ids) it's still not possible to match every possible input onto 11 bytes.

Comment: alright...if i do away with the requirement of regenerating the input and use some hashing algorithm to generate the identifiers from the input, the output size being still the same ie 11 bytes; DOES IT WORK?? i guess MD5 could do a little help here..i have come across some threads regarding this...

Comment: ohh...i guess the collision rate might be higher right??..:(:(:(

Comment: @nowfal: of course you can use MD5 or any other hashing algorithm and get a *reasonably unique* identifier that will *probably* not have many (or any) collisions, but there is **no guarantee**.

Answer (score 0):

Less than 11 bytes means maximum 10 bytes.

<strike>8^10 is 1073741824.</strike> 

2^80 is a huge number.

So if you take your hexvalue, and take it modulo that number, you should fit into the 10 bytes. Convert the remainder back to hex.

Regenerating the input will not be possible. If your input is allowed to be longer than 11 bytes, it will not be possible. That would be an endless compression.

Comment: I'm sorry the math was wrong. However, I guess 2^80, not 2^88 is the right answer. (for this mathematical question, not your question). If you can exclude 20% of the bytes for your input, it could get interesting, if you try to represent 100 elements of a subset of bytes with 80 bytes.

Comment: can you please explain why the regeneration is impossible if at all we are able to generate a unique hexadecimal value after doing away with the output size requirement(11 bytes)

Comment: Pardon, I'm not sure I got you right. Now the input is less than 100 bytes, and the output might be 100 bytes as well, which would be 50 hexadecimal ciphers? Then the regeneration may be possible, if you use an bijective mapping - every input produces one output, and every output one input. Well - that's just a rephrasing of your question, is it?

Comment: yes...thats what i meant...anyways i would go for the hashing since i am doing away with the regeneration part....thanks –